# json_decode expects parameter 1 to be string, says array is given. Why doesn't my string pass properly?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

So, I've been struggling with this for the entire weekend and I still can't figure out what's wrong. I'm trying to pass some data through `json_decode` to be able to save it to a file and I keep getting the error it expects a string but an array is given. I'm using jQuery and PHP.

The data I send through the ajax call is, according to `console.log(noBrack)`:

```
{"ID":2,"LLID":"LLID2","volNaam":"Test - 0","norm":"Zicht","instalDatum":"17-11-2017","endDate":"18-11-2017","serie":"0","klant":"Testklant","file":"data/Testklant (Heerenveen)/LLID2.json","gelDat":"27-10-2018"}
```

My Ajax call is:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'quickGrade.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: noBrack,
  datatype: 'json',
  success:function(data){
    alert(data );
  }
});
```

My PHP code is:

```
$testSave = 'data/gradeTest.json';
$decode = json_decode($_POST, true);
file_put_contents($testSave, $decode);
```

Can anyone find out what I'm doing wrong? I've tested my string with an online json_decode tester and it said it was valid so I'm kinda hardstuck here.

Comment: is `noBrack` a string or  a `json`?

Comment: You are trying to json decode $_Post, which is an array. Try to access the wanted element in that array, like $_POST['your key'].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are sending data will give you $_POST array in php code. So actually you do not need to decode because the data is coming as $_POST array not a JSON string.

Comment: How would I go about properly putting it in a file then? If I try to put file_put_contents($testSave, $_POST); it returns an empty file.

Comment: @BlackRose00101 do it like this: `$decode = json_encode($_POST);`

Comment: You please give it a try and you would get what you want.

Comment: This returns it as {"-entire array-" : " "}, is this supposed to happen? I wouldn't know how to properly process that in other parts of my code.

Comment: Can you tell me what you want to achieve? Why do you want to store json into a file?

Comment: I'm using json files as simplified databases. The main purpose of the code is to update one of the values and then push it back into the file to load it back in on different pages not directly linked to this page.

Comment: ok, did you check using `print_r($testSave);die;` variable if it is reading the file content?

Comment: Your code seems ok. It would store the json encoded data to the file mentioned. So in your case, its not putting the content at all or its not able to retain the json format??

Comment: @BlackRose00101, by the way would you please accept the answer because it is the solution to your issue mentioned in the question.

Comment: print_r($testSave);die; returns the file properly. I've been doing some screwing around and I think I can find a way to make it work. Is there a way for me to push the key of an array into the file instead of the value?

Comment: I've found a way to make it work by pushing the array key, which properly pushes it as a json. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Happy to help @BlackRose00101. Thank you so much for accepting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `json_encode` to get JSON string to store in file. Because $_POST is an array, so you can't decode it like a Json string.

Your code will become this:

```
$testSave = 'data/gradeTest.json';
file_put_contents($testSave, json_encode($_POST));
```

You can read more about:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: I've tried this but it returns it as {"-entire array-" : " "}. Is there some function to format this into a proper json quickly or do I need to find another workaround?